# Convert character factor into integer in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I had a data set which contain more than 200 category , for applying machine learning algorithm i want to convert each category into an unique integer number . How can i do this ? category is a factor type with more than 200 levels . Each level is character type like "Musical" or "Performance Art" etc
here is my sample code but it does not work it produce NA for all category

```
factorconvert <- function(f){as.numeric(levels(dataset$category))[dataset$category]}
dataset$category<- lapply(dataset$category, factorconvert)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
dataset= data.frame(category = c("Musical", "Performance Art","Musical","Play"), id_number = 1:4)
dataset$category =as.numeric(dataset$category)
```

Comment: Try to explain your answer too please instead of posting plain code. It will be more helpful!

Comment: Why you use id_number ?